# Total power conservation in transformer

Tags: transformer, coupling

Does the equation V1 X I1 = V2 X I2 hold for a transformer when coefficient of coupling is less than unity? Or does the coefficient have no relevance?

Comment: No, not when it is less than unity. The equation is only true for ideal transformers. In real transformers, some power is always lost. But it is still a useful equation.

Comment: Is there any equation relating coefficient of coupling with transferred power

Answer (score 1):

The equation is for an ideal transformer.

The efficiency of a transformer is defined as the ratio of the output power to the output power plus the losses. The losses depend on the transformer application circuit. For example, a heavily loaded transformer will have more loss due to the winding resistance.

The coupling coefficient does appear in the efficiency calculation, so yes it is relevant. However, the coupling coefficient is often translated to 'leakage inductance'. There is a straightforward calculation to translate coupling coefficient into [leakage inductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leakage_inductance).

See the [Radiotron Designer's Handbook Fourth Edition](http://www.tubebooks.org/Books/RDH4.pdf) page 204 to 206 for how to calculate transformer efficiency accounting for leakage inductance and other losses.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent energy loss resulting from a coupling factor of less than unity.

Such a transformer can be modeled as an ideal transformer with an ideal inductor in series with the primary and/or secondary.

There are no *energy* loss sources in that arrangement, however the voltage will drop as more current is drawn and the current will lag the voltage by more than it would be with an ideal transformer. So the **regulation** is negatively affected.

Transformer energy losses come from core losses and copper losses.

Answer (score 0):

Your title is this: -

> Total power conservation in transformer

But you are talking about VxI in the body of your question and this isn't necessarily power (watts that can heat up something and that consumers are billed for).

If your question was "is power conserved when the coupling is less than 100%" then the answer is YES with the normal transformer provisos/smallprint: -

- No copper losses
- No eddy current losses
- No core saturation

OK going back to VXI not being true power: -

[image]

What you appear to be describing in the body of your question is `apparent power` and not `real power`. With apparent power (VA), and less coupling, the output VA falls whilst the input VA doesn't fall by the same amount.

But, the bottom line is that if transformer losses can be ignored, output power will equal input power just as it is for a 100% coupled transformer.

Comment: By total power I meant the apparant power, which is the real power and reactive power added vectorialy. I know that real power won't be 'lost' unless there is some dissipative element. However, the first answer states that coupling ratio does indeed pop up in the efficiency calculations. I'm confused. Is efficiency calculated for real power or apparent?

Comment: @MdAjwaadZamanQuashef For a lossless transformer that isn't 100% coupled then no, coupling factor does not affect (real) power transfer efficiency. The answer you accepted appears to be at best, misleading. I do not see the relevance of calculating "efficiency" for apparent powers.

Comment: In isolation, lossless mutually-coupled inductors (aka a transformer) are lossless. Depending on the surrounding circuitry, the leakage inductance may or may not be an important term for calculating the efficiency of the overall circuit. In the circuits that I have worked on, it is usually one of the important efficiency considerations.  See http://www.eetimes.com/author.asp?doc_id=1328068 for example, "Another significant loss comes from the energy stored in the leakage inductance of the transformer, which is dissipated in a clamping circuit." The loss happens in the surrounding circuitry.

Comment: The same thing happens in an RC lowpass filter. There is energy loss at some frequency, and the energy is converted to heat in the resistor. In the calculation of the loss as a function of frequency, the value of the capacitor is still important. In many (but not all) power circuits, leakage inductance forms a similar lossy filter, and its value appears in a loss calculation.

Comment: @TomAnderson I fail to see the important relevance of the design you linked - the question was quite general in nature so focussing on an SMPS may not be that helpful. I'm also struggling to see why you mention an RC filter. This is a question about transformers and leakage so efficiency is 100% unless there are some loss mechanisms (and I've explained those).

Comment: @Andyaka The reason that I mention the surrounding circuitry is the addition to the question "Is there any equation relating coefficient of coupling with transferred power?". To answer this, the transformer has to be in some sort of circuit. a common transformer circuit these days is an SMPS.

Comment: @Andyaka Part of the confusion is that we are really talking about ideal mutually coupled inductors, because ideal transformers always have a coupling of 1. (Ideal transformers have infinite inductance and pass DC. If the coupling coefficient is not 1, the transformer also has infinite leakage inductance, and usually won't transfer energy.) When ideal coupled inductors are placed in a real-world circuits, the leakage inductance often (but not always) causes loss somewhere else in the circuit. These losses are not in the ideal inductor, but only because it is has been assumed to be lossless.

Comment: I'm not talking about infinite inductance.